# Percent in URL causing issues

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a filename that I need to download that has a `%` in the filename.  The problem is that when the URL is generated, the encoded URL changes the `%` to `%25`.  This appears to be correct from a visual perspective, but when you try to download the file it fails to find it.  Any ideas?

`NavigateUrl = "GetAttachment.ashx?eKey=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(row[0].ToString());`

Comment: How are you downloading the file? Maybe your url gets double-encoded, or never-decoded on the server side.

Comment: I believe by default `%` is input in a URL when there is a *space* inbetween ie: `.com/this site` may generate: `.com/this%site`.  So you may be able to eliminate the spaces to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to html decode it, `%25` is html encoded (hex) value of `%` sign. You can do it with [`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)

Comment: The problem I have is that the code is already using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` which is where I believe the problem is.

Comment: Makes sense, `UrlEncode` will hex encode all special characters, so space will become `%20` and `%` will become `%25`. Now, as I think, you have to `UrlDecode` the `eKey` parameter inside `GetAttachment` code.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by re-naming the path/file to not include a "%" if that's possible. Personally I attempt and would suggest leaving spaces and most symbols out of URL links and other forms of data that is being converted such as database inserts, and file names :) Good luck with your project!

Comment: I cant control user file naming conventions.

Comment: You could add validation in the form.